# Как сравнить первый char в массиве с несколькими char`ами?

Tags: java, char, equals

Нужно сравнить первый символ `сhar` массива с гласными буквами (а, у, о, ы, и, э, я, ю, ё, е).

```
if (chars[0]=='гласные буквы')
```

чтобы при любой гласной было `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Есть отсортировать гласные буквы по порядку возрастания charcode-ов и сохранить их в массиве, то можно воспользоваться бинарным поиском:

```
char[] chars = "юла".toCharArray();
char[] letters = { 'а', 'е', 'и', 'о', 'у', 'ы', 'э', 'ю', 'я', 'ё' };
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(letters, chars[0]);
System.out.println(index >= 0);
```

---

Если отсортировать массив гласных букв по какой-то причине нельзя (или почему-то нельзя пользоваться бинарным поиском), то можно просто создать массив всех гласных букв и пройтись по нему, сравнивая каждую букву с первой буквой исходного массива (которая, кстати, имеет индекс 0, а не 1):

```
public static boolean containsLetter(char[] letters, char c)
{
    for (char letter : letters)
    {
        if (letter == c)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

И пример использования:

```
char[] chars = "юла".toCharArray();
char[] letters = { 'а', 'у', 'о', 'ы', 'и', 'э', 'я', 'ю', 'ё', 'е' };
System.out.println(containsLetter(letters, chars[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать `Set` с гласными буквами и проверять буквы на вхождение в него:

```java
public class Test {
    private static final HashSet<Character> vowels =
            new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('а','о','у','ы','э','я','ё','ю','и','е'));

    public static boolean isVowel(char letter) {
        return vowels.contains(letter);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isVowel('а')); // true
        System.out.println(isVowel('е')); // true
        System.out.println(isVowel('ж')); // false
    }
}
```