# Как сравнить char элементы массива между собой?

Tags: java

Как сравнить `char` элементы массива между собой? Нужно ли переводить их в `String`?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сравнить первый char в массиве с несколькими char\`ами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655377/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-char-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-char%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет не нужно. `char` это примитивный тип (не путать с классом `Character`) и для него определены все операции сравнения `==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`

```
char[] a = {'a', 'a', 'b'};

System.out.println(a[0] == a[1]);  // true
System.out.println(a[0] != a[2]);  // true
System.out.println(a[0] < a[2]);  // true
System.out.println(a[0] == 'a');  // true
System.out.println(a[0] == "a".charAt(0));  // true
```

Comment: а как сравить все элементы с одним, допустим 'X'?

Comment: @plaza2009 так и сравнивать `if (a[i] == 'X')...`